# Shopify Products API call with multiple parameters

Tags: ios, shopify

I am working with the Shopify API. We have a single custom collection with two products in it for testing.  I'm working on a mobile platform, so I would like to limit the amount of data I need to pull. Therefore, I would like to get all products by collection (for sorting within the app) and only if it has been updated since the last time the app checked shopify.

I can get all products updated as such:

```
https://VAR1:VAR2@MYSHOPIFY/admin/products.json?updated_at_min=updatedTime
```

I can also get all products in a collection as such:

```
https://VAR1:VAR2@MYSHOPIFY/admin/products.json?collection_id=cID
```

However when I put them together:

```
https://VAR1:VAR2@MYSHOPIFY/admin/products.json?updated_at_min=updatedTime&collection_id=cID
```

I get "Invalid query". Is there anyway to pass two parameters to the Shopify API?

Comment: We can pass two parameters just like you did. I tested it using cURL, and i got proper response.

Comment: Hmm... it is strange that I cannot then. Thanks for the info.